# LaTeX Beamer : distribute items evenly inside each frame

Tags: latex, spacing, beamer

I have a Beamer presentation and I'd like to get the items of an itemize environment evenly spaced in each frame.

For instance, using the option `\frame[t]` gets all the content of a frame top aligned. How can I "vertically justify" the items, i.e. distribute them evenly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Insert `\vfill` between your content (items, images, text, etc.) where you want space to be added. This will automatically share the available space between all occurrences of `\vfill`.

Answer (score 0):

[t] is an alignment option meaning top align. Just call \frame{...} and the content will be centered.